# Select this input during a blur event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two fields with the same name. And when I do the blur event on one of them, I want only the one I am currently on to be affected. When I write on an input, the two are affected, I have a code to verify an email field, and therefore I would like to use it without having to duplicate my javascript code.

This is example : https://codepen.io/MehdiX/pen/PowXweR

```js
let email_newsletter = $('input[name="email_newsletter"]');

let verifier_newsletter = false;

email_newsletter.blur(function()
{  
    if(confirmEmail(email_newsletter.val()))
    {
        email_newsletter.removeClass('__invalid');
        email_newsletter.addClass('__valid');
        verifier_newsletter = true;
    }
    else
    {
       email_newsletter.removeClass('__valid');
       email_newsletter.addClass('__invalid');
    }
});



/*  REGEX EMAIL */

function confirmEmail(email) {
    let regx_email = /^[a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._-]{2,}\.[a-z]{2,4}$/;
    if(regx_email.test(email)){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

```css
.__invalid {
  border:2px solid red;
}

.__valid {
  border:2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="modal" action="index.php?action=subscribeNewsletter">
 <div class="form-group">
  <input type="email" name="email_newsletter" class="form-control" placeholder="Entrez votre E-Mail" required>
 </div>

 <button type="submit" name="submit_newsletter" class='p-2 rounded'>Valider</button>
</form>

<form action="index.php?action=subscribeNewsletter" method="post" class="subscribe_newsletter">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="email_newsletter">Inscrivez-vous ici :</label>
  <input type="email" name="email_newsletter" class="form-control" placeholder="Entrez votre E-Mail" required>
 </div>
</form>
```

Is it possible to assign a single element using the same name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `$(this)` to get the input object which is blured instead of all inputs. See below code

```js
let email_newsletter = $('input[name="email_newsletter"]');
let verifier_newsletter = false;

email_newsletter.blur(function()
{  
    if(confirmEmail($(this).val()))
    {
        $(this).removeClass('__invalid');
        $(this).addClass('__valid');
        verifier_newsletter = true;
    }
    else
    {
       $(this).removeClass('__valid');
       $(this).addClass('__invalid');
    }
});



/*  REGEX EMAIL */

function confirmEmail(email) {
    let regx_email = /^[a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._-]{2,}\.[a-z]{2,4}$/;
    if(regx_email.test(email)){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

```css
.__invalid {
  border:2px solid red;
}

.__valid {
  border:2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="modal" action="index.php?action=subscribeNewsletter">
 <div class="form-group">
  <input type="email" name="email_newsletter" class="form-control" placeholder="Entrez votre E-Mail" required>
 </div>

 <button type="submit" name="submit_newsletter" class='p-2 rounded'>Valider</button>
</form>

<form action="index.php?action=subscribeNewsletter" method="post" class="subscribe_newsletter">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="email_newsletter">Inscrivez-vous ici :</label>
  <input type="email" name="email_newsletter" class="form-control" placeholder="Entrez votre E-Mail" required>
 </div>
</form>
```